# laravel parent constructor does not called child constructor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2,

I have created admin controller and added logic to check admin role in constructor

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Sentinel;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

  public function __construct()
  {
    if(Sentinel::check())
    {
        if(!Sentinel::inRole('admin'))
        {
            return redirect("login");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect("login");
    }
  }

}
```

and I extends this controller on some admin controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Sentinel;
use App\User;
use DB;

class UserController extends AdminController
{

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }
}
```

When I call user controller admin constructor is called but return function is not working properly, if I add die; before return it get die, but after return notthing is affected.
so it doesn't return redirect function properly.

Answer (score 2):

The ugly workaround would be to pass a boolean param to Papa indicating that you do not wish to parse the code contained in it's constructor. i.e:

```
// main class that everything inherits
class Grandpa extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

}

class Papa extends Grandpa
{
    public function __construct($bypass = false)
    {
        // only perform actions inside if not bypassing
        if (!$bypass) {

        }
        // call Grandpa's constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Kiddo extends Papa
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $bypassPapa = true;
        parent::__construct($bypassPapa);
    }
}
```